# I have a complicated ruby object, how can I display all its methods and variables?

Tags: ruby

I have a complicated ruby object, how can I display all its methods and variables?

Is there some kind of meta call to pretty print all its values, methods and variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing as below :

```
object.class.instance_methods # => [:meth1, :meth2,...]
object.instance_variables # => [:@var1, :@var2,..]
```

Now below will give you values of all variables of an object.

```
object.instance_variables.map { |var| object.instance_variable_get(var) }
```

Docs are :-

- [`instance_variables`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-instance_variables)
- [`instance_variable_get`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_get)
- [`instance_methods`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Module.html#method-i-instance_methods)

Comment: I find appending `.sort` makes life a little easier when scanning the results of `.instance_methods` and `.instance_variables`.

Comment: Also really helpful is `grep` ([doc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep)). Say you only want methods containing an question mark (which can only appear at the end): `User.instance_methods.grep /\?/` or just filter by name `.grep /^to_/`.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on what @Arup said:

- To obtain all constants defined for a class or module, use `MyClass.constants`.
- To get all class variables (e.g., @@a), use `my_class.class_variables`.
- To get all class instance_variables (e.g., @a), use `my_class.instance_variables`.
- To get all class methods, use `my_class.singleton_class.instance_methods`.
- Sometimes you want just the constants, instance methods, class methods, class variables, class instance variables or instance variables that you have defined for a particular class (or, for methods, a particular module).  To retrieve only those (that is, to exclude ones defined by a classes' or module's ancestors), use `my_class.instance_methods(false)`,  `my_object.instance_variables(false)`, etc.

**Example**

```
module M
  M_constant = "M constant" 
  def m_method
    puts "M#m_instance_method"
  end
end

class C
  include M
  attr_accessor :c_instance_variable

  C_constant = "C constant"

  @@c_class_variable = 4

  def self.c_class_method1
    puts "c_class_method1"
  end

  def c_method
    @c_instance_variable = 0
    puts "c_instance_method"
  end

  class << self
    attr_accessor :c_class_instance_variable
    @c_class_instance_variable = 5
    def c_class_method1
      puts "c_class_method1"
    end
  end
end

class D < C
end
```

**Objects**

```
M.constants 
  #=> [:M_constant] 
C.constants
  #=> [:A, :C_constant, :M_constant] 
C.constants(false) 
  #=> [:A, :C_constant] 
D.constants 
  #=> [:A, :C_constant, :M_constant] 
D.constants(false) 
  #=> [] 

C.class_variables
  #=> [:@@c_class_variable] 
C.class_variables(false)
  #=> [:@@c_class_variable] 
D.class_variables
  #=> [:@@c_class_variable] 
D.class_variables(false)
  #=> []

C.new.instance_variables
  #=> [:@c_instance_variable]
D.new.instance_variables
  #=> []

M.instance_methods
  #=> [:m_instance_method]
C.instance_methods.size
  #=> 57 
C.instance_methods(false)
  #=> [:c_instance_variable, :c_instance_variable=, :c_method] 
D.instance_methods.size
  #=> 57 
D.instance_methods(false)
  #=> [] 

C.singleton_class.instance_methods.size
  #=> 102 
C.singleton_class.instance_methods(false)
  #=> [:c_class_method1, :c_class_instance_variable,
  #    :c_class_instance_variable=] 
D.singleton_class.instance_methods.size
  #=> 102 
D.singleton_class.instance_methods(false)
  #=> []
```